# checking integers in String

Tags: c#

I'm checking a string whether it has integers or anything else in function Parse().
Here is my Code

```
static public int input()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter The Number Of Student You Want to get Record");
        int x;
        string inputString = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(inputString, out  x))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(inputString + " Is Integer");
            return x= Convert.ToInt32(inputString);
        }
        else
        {
            input();
        }
        return x;

    }
```

And full code is:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num = 0;
        string[] names = new string[] { };
        long[] fee = new long[] { };
        string[] className = new string[] { };

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Option You Want: \nA:Enter Student Record\nB:Display Student Record\nQ:Exit");
            string option =null;
            option =Console.ReadLine();
            switch (option)
            {
                case "A":
                case "a":
                   {

                        num = input();
                        names = new string[num];
                        fee = new long[num];
                        className = new string[num];
                        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Enter Name Of Student:{0}",i); 
                            Console.Write("Enter Student Name: "); names[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.Write("Enter Student Fee: "); fee[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                            Console.Write("Enter Student Class Name: "); className[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case "B":
                case "b":
                    {

                        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Record of Student: {0}",i);
                            Console.WriteLine("Name: "+names[i]+ "\nFee: " + fee[i]+ "\nClass Name: " + className[i]);
                            //Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}\n Class Name: {1}\n Fee: {3}\n",names[i],className[i],fee[i]);
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                case "Q":
                case "q":
                    {
                        Environment.Exit(1);
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Option");
                        break;
                    }

            }
        } while (true);
    }
```

But The problem is when I enters char instead of int and it works fine and calls itself again but if 2nd time or after 2nd time I input int then does not take input of students and instead it repeats the LOOP again.
So what's the problem, is problem in Input Function????

Comment: `return input();`instead of just calling `input();`

Comment: Thanks it worked. What could be the problem without using it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to find the INTs. Also you should call

```
return input();
```

instead of

```
input();
```

new method:

```
static public int input(){
       Console.WriteLine("Enter The Number Of Student You Want to get Record");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        if (Regex.IsMatch(input, @"\d+"))
        {
            return int.Parse(Regex.Match(input, @"\d+").Value);
        }
        else
        {
            return input();
        }
}
```

Comment: No Problem glad to help

Comment: Sure what do you need?

Comment: when declaring data members in Class in C#. if i want to declare builtin objects so what should I create only pointer or whole object i.e DateTime DOB
OR DateTime DOB=new DateTime(); while declaring in class ????

Comment: Declare it as Datetime DOB but initialize it in your constructor

Comment: If you don't initialize it you will receive an null pointer exception

Answer (score -3):

I'm assuming you're a student. I started out with C# doing the same stuff. Which I wouldn't do anymore but since you are doing it. I'd recommend using goto, making this method recursive is a no no.

```
static public int input()
    {
     Prompt:
        Console.WriteLine("Enter The Number Of Student You Want to get Record");
        int x;
        string inputString = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(inputString, out  x))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(inputString + " Is Integer");
            return x;
        }
        else
        {
            goto Prompt;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Don't EVER use goto in such a high level language as C#

Comment: Goto here is much better than recursive call. People say, never use Goto in C#.. well answer me this, why is it in the language then? 
 Goto is actually very useful with Console.Writeline prompts.

Comment: An infinite loop would be a fine alternative to `goto`.

Comment: @Proximo it is there because switch cases are internally treated as goto. It is also useful in rare cases, but certainly not this one. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx)